# WebBrowser.url not working some times in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I set url value of a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) object on an event. Sometimes setting up of this value is not getting reflected in webBrowser.

The code I used is

```
webBrowser.Url= new Uri("www.google.com")
```

I also tried `webBrowser.Navigate()` but same behavior. Any ideas why it could be happening and what to do to overcome this?

Comment: What do you mean that the value is not getting reflected in the web browser? Do you mean that it does not navigate to that uri?

Comment: @MatthewRz Yes its not navigating to the uri. Actually what  I have noticed, I am doing webBrowser.Url = url1 and again doing webBrowser.Url = url2 its navigating to url1 only. It's not navigating to url2. I tried to navigate to url2 using WebBrowserDocumentCompleted but still same behavior.

Comment: If webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com")) does not work then there might be something wrong other than the code. If it nothing works then you code post all of the code that involves the issue so I could try and pin-point the error.

Comment: At the time of browser rendering (Control initialization) I am doing webBrowser1.Navigate(new Url("google.com")), instantly I am doing webBrowser1.Navigate(new Url("facebook.com")), but its going to google com in some cases but ideally it should redirect to facebook.com ultimately for all the cases. While debugging I noticed WebBroser1.url is null even after the first navigation call. Also after above initialization, if I externally set the url of browser it redirects fine. Problem is with only when initilization is happening. Does it give some hint to you to catch the problem ?

Comment: So you're saying that you are trying to redirect the webBrowser to google, then straight after that to facebook, but it does not go to facebook? This is very weird, could you please post some of the initialization code around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although very old question, for people visiting this, please check `AllowNavigation` property set on the `WebBrowser` instance.

As per MSDN documentation -

> This property does not prevent you from loading an initial page by
>   setting the Url, DocumentText or DocumentStream property, but will
>   prevent all subsequent navigation.

You can find more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.allownavigation(v=vs.110).aspx).